# TypeScript `unknown` doesn't allow non-unknown types in function parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why doesn't this work?

```
const x: unknown[] = ['x', 32, true]; // OK
const y: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown = (xx: number) => {}; // ERROR

// Type '(xx: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown'.
//  Types of parameters 'xx' and 'args' are incompatible.
//    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'. ts(2322)
```

My goal is to make sure that `y` is any runnable function. I was trying not to use `any`.
Hope to improve my understanding of how `unknown` works in this case.

Comment: What you're doing isn't safe.  Presumably you would want `const y: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown = (xx: number) => xx.toFixed()` to compile, but then `y("x", 32, true)` would be accepted by the compiler and subsequently blow up at runtime.  What do you plan to do with `y` once it exists?  That will determine how it should be declared.

Comment: I'm trying to make a definition for a module within the dependency injection library `didi` which isn't very type-safe either. Module declarations are one of the following: `['type', FunctionConstructor]`, `['factory', FactoryFunction]`, `['value', unknown]`.

Comment: I used the example above to simplify the reason for the error. `y` should actually return something specific. I left it empty for simplicity. But there's no way I know the function parameters of every factory function I may want to use for injection later on. I use unknown since `didi` doesn't have the type bindings to give me each factory function's return type when I inject anyway, so I'm essentially casting the injected value's type at the destination.

Comment: There is a (mostly) safe top type for functions; it's `(...args: never) => unknown`.  It's the `unknown` of functions.  But as such, it's almost useless to have a value annotated of that type; the compiler won't let you call it.  This is the general tradeoff with types; the less you specify about a type, the easier it is to produce values of that type and the harder it is to consume values of that type. I wish you'd [edit] to show a [mre] of someone *using* `y`, since that drives the answer. Perhaps you don't want to annotate at all and instead use `satisfies` like [this](//tsplay.dev/WzaXem)?

Comment: Okay. I can edit it and make something that uses `didi`. But that will take some time. `satisfies` actually does exactly what I wanted. And your example with `(...args:never)` also works since `didi` calls these functions and it's not using typescript--seems like cheating. Curious why these work but not `unknown` as an annotation.

Comment: If you're not calling the functions in TypeScript then I guess I don't need a [mre].  I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Must make a correction to what I said about `didi` for future readers: Turns out one of the typedefs it has `ServiceDeclaration` is exactly what I wanted to make. So I didn't have to make my own. This has been very educational, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function types are *contravariant* in their parameter types; see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more details.  Contravariance means the direction of assignability flips; if `T` is assignable to `U`, then `(...u: U) => void` is assignable to `(...t: T) => void` and not vice versa.  This is necessary for type safety. Picture the direction of data flow: if you want fruit then I can give you an apple, but if you want something that will eat all your fruit I can't give you something that eats only apples.

---

The function type `(xx: number) => void` is equivalent to `(...args: [number]) => void`, and you cannot assign that to `(...args: unknown[]) => void`.  Yes, `[number]` is assignable to `unknown[]`, but that's not the direction we care about.  Your assignment is therefore unsafe.  If this worked:

```
const y: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown =
    (xx: number) => xx.toFixed(); // should this be allowed?
```

Then you'd be able to call `y()` with any set of arguments you wanted without a compiler error, but hit a runtime error:

```
y("x", 32, true); // no compiler error
//  error! xx.toFixed is not a function
```

Widening the input argument list to `unknown[]` has the effect of making the function type very narrow, since most functions do not accept all possible argument lists.

---

So if you really want a type to which any function at all should be assigned, you'd need to *narrow* the input argument list to a type that cannot accept *any* inputs, like this:

```
type SomeFunction = (...args: never) => unknown;
const y: SomeFunction = (xx: number) => xx.toFixed(); // okay
// const y: SomeFunction
```

That works because `SomeFunction` is essentially uncallable (well, it should be; there's an outstanding bug at [ms/TS#48840](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48840)).  If I ask you for a function that I'm not going to call, you can safely hand me any function at all.  Conversely if you hand me a function and I don't know what arguments it accepts, I had better not try to call it.

So that works, but... it's kind of useless.  Once you have `y` you can't do anything with it:

```
y(123); // error, oops doesn't know about its argument types anymore
```

For the use case in your question I guess that's fine, since you are passing these uncallable functions to non-TypeScript code to something which has no knowledge of or regard for our type safety rules.

---

Still, for others who might be reading, it might be more useful to *verify* that a value can be assigned to a type without *widening* it to that type.  So instead of
[annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `y` as `SomeFunction`, we can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to just check it against that type:

```
const y = ((xx: number) => xx.toFixed()) satisfies SomeFunction;
// const y: (xx: number) => string
```

That compiles (but would fail if you wrote, say, `const y = "oops" satisifies SomeFunction`), and `y` is still known to be `(xx: number) => string`.  So you still can call it:

```
y(123); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeBYAUEkUvGsFAC5ICeAXEgBQB0LIATgOZT0CuwA1sDQB3YAG0AugEokAXgB8SPoJHA5BYpsYAPbfWA8wAIwhsZCpLqYU0AMQCW2iABMGUgNwbi1BgCJtvgA0SADMAEzBFGw8EB5IAPTxSEIkaGAw9gA2pkimbGhsXkSJSIC8G4ClO7ls+WwAhJba1naOLkj2WEJUIEgAZnzwFPZkBAC+BASgkLAIyADKID0QAEI8FACqUBDZUFh4+EVIFNQwc2kQtv2DZHKMLEzsXPoQAG6m5orKQqKehMSk5FQ6EhZmcLsABkM1LIdHpkoYTGY5IorDYHE5XB4DiV-pQaPQQZAwRDhr8iD4AIxhEJxEp5ArBNAYLDONDQYAAcioKmESBARjQqzaFCwD0MEGAVCOJxFwGoYAKEHG+DG+3wk2gcEQwIWEAAgsBnBsIH1MjglZopadCZdITdmKxONxki83kilAIvsAfpocYC7QxdPp4a6LCjmui3DIoCBBlAevZoMDQTayN7iNiyLigQHYQZjCHFJQ2PZgBwDhSqTSkmh+CBqEqVUA)

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't this work?

The following is an error:

```
const x: unknown[] = ['x', 32, true]; // OK
const y: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown = (xx: number) => {}; // ERROR
```

Because of the same reason why this is an error:

```
const x: unknown = 123; // OK 
const y: number = x; // ERROR: cannot assign unknown to number
```

Reason Simplified: You cannot assign unknown to anything else without first checking its runtime value.