Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'
I encounter Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number' when trying to implement something like this:
interface Foo<V = unknown> {
    foo: (value: V) => void
}

class Bar implements Foo<number> {
    foo(v: number) {}
}

function test(foo: Foo): void {}

test(new Bar) // complains:

// Argument of type 'Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo<unknown>'.
//   Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
//     Type '(v: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown) => void'.
//       Types of parameters 'v' and 'value' are incompatible.
//         Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)

Why does it behave like this and how can I redesign this considering that test should be able to get different implementations of Foo, e.g.
class Bar2 implements Foo<string> {
    foo(v: string) {}
}


Type assertion:
test(new Bar as Foo) // it doesn't complain now, but imo it's dirty and bad DX workaround


Tried to replace unknown in Foo with union type e.g. string | number | ..., but it didn't help.



Why not propagate the generic to test, function test<T>(foo: Foo<T>) { /* ... */ }

You've told the compiler that test takes a Foo and aren't passing any type parameter, so it defaults to unknown. In other words, it's as if you wrote function test(foo: Foo<unknown>) {} and the compiler is looking at the signature of test and seeing the mismatch with the Bar argument. You need to take jonrsharpe's advice and propagate a generic.

@jonrsharpe because I want Foo implementations to be responsible for the type of value. Considering your answer what will happen if I call test<string>(new Bar)?
Also what if test accepts collection of  Foo objects and each of which got different value type?

How is that a reason not to do it?! If you called test<string>(new Bar) the compiler would (correctly!) be able to tell you that this is wrong: https://tsplay.dev/wOKeyw. And do you accept a collection? Maybe T would be the union of the individual types, or a tuple of them, depending on your needs.

Affectively the main issue here is unknown cannot be assigned to anything but itself and the any type.
If you strip down your example more
type FooFn = (value: unknown) => void
const testFooFn: FooFn = (n: number) => {} // Error 

You get a similar error to the one you get above.
Type '(n: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'FooFn'.
  Types of parameters 'n' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

One option, as suggested in the comments, is to use generics to carry over the type.
interface Foo<V = unknown> {
  foo: (value: V) => void
}

class Bar implements Foo<number> {
  foo(v: number) {
    console.log(v)
  }
}

function test<T>(foo: Foo<T>): void {}

test(new Bar()) // No Error

Another option is change unknown to any. See the differences here, but typically it's better/safer to use unknown but requires more type gymnastics.
interface Foo<V = any> {
  foo: (value: V) => void
}

class Bar implements Foo<number> {
  foo(v: number) {
    console.log(v)
  }
}

function test(foo: Foo): void {}

test(new Bar()) // No Error

See TSPlayground

This is a great answer for how to get around the problem, but why is it a problem in the first place?  Why can't (v:number)=>void be assigned to a variable of type (v:unknown)=>void, since number is narrower than unknown?  Plus, the last line of the error feels misleading since number is being assigned to unknown, why does it say "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'"  At the very least, it is a very confusing error message.

I'm trying to have an array of (value: unknown) => void and push functions into it of different parameter types.  It's configurations of grid columns where each column's data type can be different.  With this, I cannot "carry over the type".  It feels like I must use any, which means that TypeScript cannot handle this situation.  Boo.

Yeah true, I think this post does a good job explaining how the function parameter types are contravariant. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964072/6943587
